# In R, how do I reproject from the MODIS sinusoidal projection to latlong (ellps=WGS84) projection

Tags: r, r-raster, spatial-data-frame, reprojection-error, r-modis

I have managed to extract MODIS land cover data from an HDF file and put it into a raster.

```
library(gdalUtils) #? gdal_translate?
library(raster)
sds <- get_subdatasets(".......myfileplath/file.hdf")
# Isolate the name of the first sds
name <- sds[5]
filename <- '2009test.tif'
gdal_translate(sds[5], dst_dataset = filename)
# Load the Geotiff created into R
r <- raster(filename)
```

I want to put it into a dataframe but reproject it from the original sinusoidal which is `+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs`, I think.

To a normal ellipsoid/WGS84 one that is compatible with other datasets I'm analyzing.

This is what I've tried and seemed to work:

```
sr <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0' 
 projected_raster <- projectRaster(r, crs = sr)
```

However, when I then put my my landcover data in this new projection into a data frame all the landcover values have gone to NA.

This is what the dataframe looked like in a sinu projection (the 4's being a land cover classifications)

```
DF <-  as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
head(DF)

#           x       y       X2009test
#1   -1111718.9 1111719         4
#2   -1111255.6 1111719         4
#3   -1110792.2 1111719         4
#4   -1110328.9 1111719         4
#5   -1109865.6 1111719         4
```

and with my reprojection it looks like this:

```
reprojected_DF <-  as.data.frame(projected_raster, xy=TRUE)
head(reprojected_DF)

#                x        y X2009test
#1   -10.173076 10.01876        NA
#2   -10.168896 10.01876        NA
#3   -10.164716 10.01876        NA
#4   -10.160536 10.01876        NA
#5   -10.156356 10.01876        NA
#6   -10.152176 10.01876        NA
#7   -10.147996 10.01876        NA
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong or how I can get the land cover coordinates to reproject properly?

Cheers!!!!

Also I read there was a NASA MODIS reprojection tool but that that no long exists / is available. Anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Thiis should work. From what you show it is hard to guess what is going on. Can you make the file available and a complete script that generates the data.frame?

Comment: Is x2009test a value? Presumably projectraster needs to make some assumptions when determining values/factor for points in new projection, so that might be a potential problem.

Comment: This is the full script I have, it generates a sinusoidal projection dataframe and then the ellipsoidal (with the NA values)

Comment: I posted it below!

Comment: Thanks for helping out btw, appreciate it (:

Comment: I have added you "answer" to your question -- you can always edit your question to improve it --- but don't add to the question in the answers--- then it becomes very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

All you are doing seems to be OK. Except that in projectRaster you should use `method="ngb"` because the numbers represent classes (I suppose).

Are you sure `reprojected_DF` has no values. Can you `show(reprojected_DF)` (it should show the min and max values if there are any. That is, it could very well be that there are some NA values around the values. In that case you may do `na.omit(reprojected_DF)`. Can you also `show(r)` to check the coordinate reference system?

Another, possibly better, option, would be to project the coordinates in `DF`, like this

```
DF <- data.frame(x=c(-1111718.9, -1111255.6, -1110792.2, -1110328.9, -1109865.6), y=c(1111719, 1111719, 1111719, 1111719, 1111719), X2009test=c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4))

library(rgdal)  
sincrs <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m"
s <- SpatialPoints(DF, proj4string=CRS(sincrs))

lonlat <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0' 

x <- spTransform(s, lonlat)
as.data.frame(x)
#          x        y X2009test
#1 -10.15209 9.997918         4
#2 -10.14786 9.997918         4
#3 -10.14362 9.997918         4
#4 -10.13939 9.997918         4
#5 -10.13516 9.997918         4
```

Note that this is in the same area as the coordinates you showed --- again suggesting that there are in fact values in your data.

An easier route might be to use the terra package (very similar to raster, but simpler and faster), and do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(".......myfileplath/file.hdf")
```

And take it from there with pretty much the same code (see ?terra for the differences)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get a list of sds names
sds <- get_subdatasets(".......myfileplath/file.hdf")

sds

# Isolate the name of the first sds
name <- sds[5]
filename <- '2009test.tif'
gdal_translate(sds[5], dst_dataset = filename)
# Load the Geotiff created into R

r <- raster(filename)

# Define the Proj.4 spatial reference 

sr <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0' 

projected_raster <- projectRaster(r, crs = sr)

DF <-  as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
DF


reprojected_DF <-  as.data.frame(projected_raster, xy=TRUE)
reprojected_DF
```

Comment: The projectRaster does not work ```Error in rgdal::checkCRSArgs_ng(uprojargs = uprojargs, SRS_string = SRS_string,  : 
  is.character(SRS_string) is not TRUE```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `MRT` is no longer available. Nevertheless, you can install `NASA's HDF-EOS to GeoTIFF Conversion Tool (HEG)`  ([see here](https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGHome.html)) to do what you need. I never used `MRT`, but I believe it's kind of the same thing. I've used `HEG` several times, and you can run in batch (in a java-based GUI or in command line/terminal) reprojection (considering `nearest neighbour` or `bilinear` interpolation) and save output data as `*.tif`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(terra)
f<-list.files(pattern="hdf")
s <- sds(f[1])
r<-s[1]
r<-project(r, "EPSG:4326")
```

The *terra* package is definitely the choice. Quicker and Safer.